# javascript split string by pattern

Tags: javascript

i want to split this string in JavaScript.

i try it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var str = "<new_a><new_b><sb_c>";
var res = str.split("<");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

result:
    new_a> , new_b> , sb_c>

i want to my result : new_a , new_b , sb_c

how can i do?

Comment: "want to", not "wanna"

Comment: *"but i don't like it!!!!!!"* is not a useful problem description. What about the result don't you like? What would you prefer instead? What prevents you modifying your code to do what you prefer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction()
{
  var str = "<new_a><new_b><sb_c>";
  str = str.replace("<","");
  str = str.replace(">"," ");
  var res = str.split(" ");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=res;
}
```

Try this code.